# How to do "You'll need to authenticate with a valid app password." when cloning Bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket, git-clone

I am trying to clone the repository. I go into the repository on Bitbucket, click "Clone", set it to HTTPS, then copy the text it gives me. I go into VS Code, click the branch on the left-hand side, click clone. I insert the command, it asks for my password and I insert my Bitbucket password. After the password I am given an error.

The error reads as follows:

> "Git: remote: You'll need to authenticate with a valid app password. You can create an app password from your account at [https://bitbucket.org/account/admin/app-passwords"](https://bitbucket.org/account/admin/app-passwords%22)

I'm using a Mac from 2011 so some things are not updated but it worked less than a month ago.

Comment: why not just clone the repo onto your computer and then use vscode to open it up?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity

Answer (score 5):

Try first and create an [HTTP access token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html) or (for the Cloud) "[App passwords](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/)"

Then provide that token/app password as a password when cloning (in command line or through VSCode).
That should authenticate you properly and allow you to clone the repository.

> This worked for me where I have cloned the repo locally before creating the app passwords.
>
> Given you have the app password created in your bitbucket repo
>
> Then update your local git repo as below
>
> ```
> git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME:APP_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/OWNER/REPO.g
> ```

The last command is for testing only, you should not include password in your URL, but use a [credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) to cache it.

Comment: Your answer links to documentation for Bitbucket Server, but this question (and your example) are about Bitbucket Cloud. Unfortunately the answer you've provided won't work - this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393902/how-do-i-obtain-an-http-access-token-from-a-bitbucket-repository-on-bitbucket-cl/70415364#70415364

Comment: @daveruinseverything Thank you. I have edited the answer to include the link to App Password (Cloud) you mention in your comment.